# Disable button when object is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When `matchList = []` is empty the button `ng-disabled="checkIfDataExists"` should be disabled. But when `matchList = []` is full the button should be enabled. How to archive that? Thanks

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('gameplanController', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$location', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', '$http', function (currentAuth, $scope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $http) {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("matches");
    var matchList = $firebaseObject(ref);

    matchList.$loaded().then(function (data) {

        $scope.checkIfDataExists = function () {
            var matchList = [];

            if(matchList.length === 0) {
                console.log("empty");
                $scope.checkIfDataExists = true
            } else {
                console.log("full");
                $scope.checkIfDataExists = false
            }

        };

    });

}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-main" ng-disabled="checkIfDataExists">{{ gametable }}</button>
```

Comment: Remove var matchList = []; from your function

Comment: Where is your button present?

Comment: Is your button wrapped inside a ng-if or ng-repeat?

Comment: Try to create a punker with the above problem

Comment: where did you called the checkIfDataExists  function

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller('gameplanController', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$location', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', '$http', function (currentAuth, $scope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $http) {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("matches");
    var matchList = $firebaseObject(ref);

    matchList.$loaded().then(function (data) {      

        var matchList = [];
        if(matchList.length === 0) {
            console.log("empty");
            $scope.checkIfDataExists = true
        } else {
            console.log("full");
            $scope.checkIfDataExists = false
        }
    });

}]);
```

Just try my changes.

Comment: try my changes now

Answer (score 0):

modify your controller simple as follow

```
app.controller('gameplanController', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$location', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', '$http', function (currentAuth, $scope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $http) {

            var ref = firebase.database().ref("matches");
            var matchList = $firebaseObject(ref);
            $scope.checkIfDataExists = false
            matchList.$loaded().then(function (data) {

                    $scope.checkIfDataExists = (matchList.length !== 0); //checkIfDataExists true when matchlist array has data
            });

        }]);
```

Comment: its disabled when matchlist is full (or matchlist has data)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to attach the matchList to the $scope and check the length directly in the NgDisable like

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default button-main" 
        ng-disabled="!matchList.length > 0">
  {{ gametable }}
</button>
```

Comment: @jglom did you attach the matchList to the $scope?

Comment: @jglom Ok, great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
$scope.checkIfDataExists = function () {

        if(matchList.length === 0) {
            console.log("empty");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("full");
            return false;
        }

    };
```

Comment: well I think its because you declare the " matchList = []" inside the function. try to remove that.